# Count down based on shipping time

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a javascript thats countdown hh/mm/ss based on time and days

> Order now and we ship your order in: 22 h 42 Min 3 Sec

Mon-Friday the order should be placed before 6PM (18:00 GMT +1)
Saturday-Sunday the order should be placed before 3PM (15:00 GMT +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can do the jist of what you are asking. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALrnK/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var day = now.getDay();
        var end;

        if(day >= 1 && day <= 5) {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 18, 0, 0, 0);    
        } else {
            end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 15, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
        var diff = new Date(timeleft);


        $("#timeleft").html("Order now and we ship your order in: " + diff.getHours() + "h " + diff.getMinutes() + "Min " + diff.getSeconds() + "Sec");

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: How would you account for timezones?